# angular-fontawesome fa-layers-counter color change

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, font-awesome, angular-fontawesome

I am using the angular-fontawesome library as part of an ionic application. I can't seem to get the fa-layer-counter component to change color away from it's default red shade.

```
<fa-layers [fixedWidth]="true">
    <fa-icon [icon]="['far', 'bell']"></fa-icon>
    <fa-layers-counter content=""></fa-layers-counter>
</fa-layers>
```

I've tried:

1. Adding a class to change the SCSS background-color like so:

```
<fa-layers [fixedWidth]="true">
    <fa-icon [icon]="['far', 'bell']"></fa-icon>
    <fa-layers-counter content="" class="color-change"></fa-layers-counter>
</fa-layers>

.color-change {
    --background-color: var(--ion-color-success) !important;
}
```

2. Tapping into the span sub-element that gets created (with element and class name):

```
<fa-layers [fixedWidth]="true">
    <fa-icon [icon]="['far', 'bell']"></fa-icon>
    <fa-layers-counter content="" class="color-change"></fa-layers-counter>
</fa-layers>

.color-change > .fa-layers-counter {
    --background-color: var(--ion-color-success) !important;
}
```

3. Styling inline.
4. Using a style other than backgorund-color.

I'm out of ideas and couldn't get anything to work. Any ideas?

Comment: if you don't want to use the default color, why not just use a generic `<div>` tag?

Comment: I want everything else that comes with the tag - location, size, content, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first issue is that you attempt to change `--background-color`, which is a [CSS variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties). This variable is not recognised by `angular-fontawesome`. So you should change `background-color` CSS property instead.

Then there are two things at play here: CSS cascades and Angular view encapsulation.

So the intuitive way is to add a class to the `<fa-layers-counter>`. It will correctly add a class and change colour of `<fa-layers-counter>` element. But the problem is that the actual dot is a `<span>` inside `<fa-layers-counter>`, which *overrides* the `background-color` value set on its parent.

```html
<fa-layers-counter class="color-change"> <!-- you set your colour here -->
  <span class="fa-layers-counter"></span> <!-- but it is overridden on the child element by the library -->
</fa-layers-counter>
```

To solve this problem `angular-fontawesome` provides [`classes` input](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/blob/master/src/lib/layers/layers-counter.component.ts#L18), which allows to assign class on the internal `<span>` element.

So `<fa-layers-counter [classes]="['change-color']"></fa-layers-counter>` would result in below markup:

```html
<fa-layers-counter>
  <span class="fa-layers-counter color-change"></span>
</fa-layers-counter>
```

However this still does not work, because of Angular's [view encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation). `color-change` class is defined in your host component and Angular will prevent it's rule to be applied to the `fa-layers-counter`'s content (which is a different component). To overcome this you need to tell Angular that you actually want to apply this to content of another component. The final solution will look like below:

```
<fa-layers-counter [classes]="['change-color']"></fa-layers-counter>

/* :host is a small precaution, to ensure that .change-color is only applied in the host's subtree. This is not required, but makes it less likely for `.change-color` class rules to leak in the unexpected place. */
:host ::ng-deep .change-color {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Here is a working example on StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z8v4ux-kof4dr